# Display data as menu from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, `categories` with column names as `id` and `cat_id`. Cat_id=0 give me Veg and Cat_id=1 gives me Non veg.

Now i have another table `menu`(columns `me_id`,`me_name` and `re_id`) having main categories and `item`(columns `item_id`,`re_id`,`me_id`,`cat_id`,`item_name` and `item_rate`) having sub_ctegories

i want out put like as below

```
    Veg Menu                Non Veg Menu      
    Main_cat1               Main_cat2
      --Sub_cat1             --Sub cat1
    Main_cat3
       --Sub_cat3
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

First of all i could not understand why you have kept `cat_id` in `item` table, secondly what is the purpose of `re_id` which is a foreign key in `item` table whereas you have already kept `me_id` as foreign key. Finally you need a foreign key in `menu` table. Some thing as `cat_id`.

Keeping that in mind your query will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM categories INNER JOIN menu ON categories.cat_id = menu.cat_id INNER JOIN item ON menu.me_id = item.me_id WHERE cat_id = 0;
```

You can change the cat_id to 1 here: `WHERE cat_id = 1` by some form input, jquery or simply by assigning id and passing parameters via url (GET method).